# Marquee in HTML without <marquee> .. </marquee>

Tags: javascript, html, marquee

I'm trying to program a scrolling text that runs smooth. The `<marquee>..</marquee>` tag doesn't work without jolting and I don't think it is good programming. I would like to do it in JavaScript but I'm a total beginner in it.

I found some codes that are easy to understand but the scrolling text that I think looks best isn't coherent to me.

Perhaps someone can explain the parts to me I don't understand.

CODE:

```
var marqueewidth="2400px"   
var marqueeheight="45px"    
var speed=1 
var pause=1 //stop by mouseover 0=no. 1=yes

var marqueecontent='<nobr><span style="font-size:40px">*** Wir wünschen einen guten Start in den Dezember!!! ***</span></nobr>'

var newspeed=speed
var pausespeed=(pause==0)? newspeed: 0

document.write('<span id="temp" style="visibility:hidden; position:absolute; top:0px; left:-9000px">'+marqueecontent+'</span>')

var actualwidth=''
var cross_marquee, ns_marquee

function populate(){
    cross_marquee= document.getElementById("marquee")
    cross_marquee.style.left=parseInt(marqueewidth)+8+"px"
    cross_marquee.innerHTML=marqueecontent
    actualwidth=document.getElementById("temp").offsetWidth
    lefttime=setInterval("scrollmarquee()",20)
}
window.onload=populate


function scrollmarquee(){
    if (parseInt(cross_marquee.style.left)>(actualwidth*(-1)+8))
        cross_marquee.style.left=parseInt(cross_marquee.style.left)-newspeed+"px"
    else
        cross_marquee.style.left=parseInt(marqueewidth)+8+"px" 
}

with (document){
        write('<div style="position:relative; top:655px; width:'+marqueewidth+'; height:'+marqueeheight+'; overflow:hidden">')
        write('<div onMouseover="newspeed=pausespeed" onMouseout="newspeed=speed">')
        write('<div id="marquee" style="position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px; "></div>')
        write('</div></div>')
}
```

Question: Why do I need the temp div ? And how can I swap the styles in CSS ?

Comment: `<nobr>`, `with`, `onClick` attribute, no semi-colons... this is some old-school code you have found.

Comment: You can use a plugin (`jQuery`) like this: http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Carousel-Marquee-Like-List-Scrolling-Plguin-For-jQuery-Scrollbox/demos/

Comment: `<marquee><nobr><span style>...</span></nobr></marquee>` - that's _mortifying_. Where did you get this snippet? Some website which its owners forgot to euthanize 10 years ago? Anyways, CSS animations are what you are likely looking for. You shouldn't use Javascript for presentation purposes unless you require unique functionality that doesn't exist natively.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, `marquee` isn't only deprecated, it's also [obsolete](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee) now.

Of course you can create a JavaScript function that simulates the effect. But it's simpler and certainly smoother to use CSS for that.

Here's an example:

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <p>Hey, how you're doing? Sorry you can't get through.</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 25px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}

.wrapper p {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 25px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  animation: marquee 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  0% { transform: translateX(100%); }
  100% { transform: translateX(-100%); }
}
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/2mquamxo/)

Comment: I have got one problem, the scrolling text stops by opening a hyperlink.. what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 5):

I just would use CSS3-animations. It works in every modern browser like a charm. You don’t need JavaScript to move an element.

If you want to switch it on and off, just add and remove a CSS class.

I just built an example in codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LGEBbx

This is the animation code:

```
@keyframes marquee {
  0% { transform: translateX(100%); }
  100% { transform: translateX(-100%); }
}
```

I hope this was the solution you’re looking for.

Comment: What do you mean with "add and remove a CSS class" ?

Comment: Just for the case you want to toggle the marquee, you could just remove the class .marquee with JavaScript, to switch the marquee animation off. This is the only case you would need JavaScript for marquee. Mentioned it just for the case you want to toggle it :)